# Raise exception if RSpec fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, newrelic

I'd like to write rake script, that runs all RSpec tests in my application. If any of the tests fails, id like to throw an Exception in the task (later on I will catch this exception in NewRelic alert system - I use it for other tasks as well).

Is it possible?

Comment: You can just notify newrelic directly, you know.

Comment: You could also check exit code of `rspec` command line tool. If it's non-zero, raise away.

Comment: I'm not sure what You mean. If my rspec fails during rake task, NewRelic will display it? According to Your second command, it may be answer I'm looking for. I will test it right away!

Comment: I meant this: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/troubleshooting/sending-new-relic-handled-errors

Comment: That's cool feature, thanks!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if that link helped solve this question, I suggest submitting it as an answer

Comment: @HunterStevens: well, how should _I_ know if it helped? :)

Comment: Actually I have a little problem...I'm calling this: ```RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)``` to run those tests in Rake task (details: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/rake-task), but I don't know how to retrieve the exit code (maybe I need to run spec by spec, not all at once)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sorry, I meant to tag OP!

Comment: @UncleChris: why don't you use [`system('rspec spec')`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) or something?

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev! I didn't know that such method like system exists... Please, combine all Your comments into response, so I can mark it as valid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need to raise an exception to let newrelic know of it. You can let newrelic know by directly posting error details to their api: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/troubleshooting/sending-new-relic-handled-errors

```
notice_error(exception, options = { })
```

where `exception` can be an exception object (`StandardError.new`, for example) or a message.

Also, you can omit all this exception business and check exit code of `rspec` command line tool. If tests are green, it'll be zero. If errors are present, it will not be zero. Something like this

```
if system('rspec spec') # return true if command was successful, false otherwise
  # if green
else
  # if red
end
```